# How to put in response some value, Django, Python

Tags: python, django

I have some Django code:

```
       def index_view( request ):
           obj = Object1()
           return render_to_response('template.html',
                    {'obj1': obj},
                     context_instance=RequestContext(request))


       def some_view( request ):
           obj2 = Object2()
           response = index_view( request )
           # how i can add obj2 to response ?
           return response
```

How I can add `obj2` to `response` from `index_view` ? 
Many Thanks.

Comment: You really need to [add your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314392/how-to-put-in-response-some-value-django-python#comment41295376_26314622) to the question because it is a critical part in trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
   def index_view(request, obj2=None):
       obj = Object1()
       return render_to_response('template.html',
                {'obj1': obj, 'obj2':obj2},
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))


   def some_view(request):
       obj2 = Object2()
       return index_view(request, obj2)
```

Comment: Why can't you change index-view?

Comment: because such functions very much and would not want to change them, because probably in response to it will be necessary to add more values ​​to which these functions do not need to know. It look like: viewgrid = {type(Manufacture()): manufacture_view,
             type(CarModel()): carmodel_view,
             type(Modification()): modification_view,
             type(Article()): article_view,
             type(Dismantle()): dismantle_view, }

Comment: the additional parameter is optional, so you can provide it, or leave it out. Do you know that for `type(Dismantle())` it's much better to write just `Dismantle`.

Answer (score 1):

pass the value when you call the `index_view`

```
def index_view( request , obj2 ):
           obj = Object1()
           return render_to_response('template.html',
                    {'obj1': obj,'obj2':obj2},
                     context_instance=RequestContext(request))


       def some_view( request ):
           obj2 = Object2()
           response = index_view( request, obj2 )
           # how i can add obj2 to response ?
           return response
```

Comment: Thank you, but this workaround not for me. some of the comments posted above

Answer (score 1):

How about [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)?

```
# app.context_processors
def foo(request):
    # Use string url compare or reverse function url:
    # request.path == 'url'
    # if request.path.startswith('url')
    # even with args:
    # reverse('admin:app_list', kwargs={'app_label': 'auth'})
    if request.path == reverse('app.views.index_view'):
        obj2 = Object2()
        return {'obj2': obj2}
    return {}

# settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = {
    ...
    'app.context_processors.foo',
}
```